# Can anyone help me replace this X figure with some text?

Tags: html, css

I just want to replace the center X figure which is menu-toggler with some text like Google which is company name that I have taken as an example here. I have even add some text here in label and it doesn't appears in correct format. I want the text to appear like a normal sentence not like one word after another. Thanks for helping me in advance.

> [My Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cBKn.jpg)

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc354c, #0abfbc);
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-toggler:hover + label, .menu-toggler:hover + label:before, .menu-toggler:hover + label:after {
  background: white;
}

.menu-toggler:checked + label {
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-toggler:checked + label:before, .menu-toggler:checked + label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.menu-toggler:checked + label:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-toggler:checked + label:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-toggler + label {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-toggler + label:before, .menu-toggler + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.menu-toggler + label:before {
  top: 10px;
}
.menu-toggler + label:after {
  top: -10px;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) a {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) a {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) a {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) a {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) a {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) a {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 1025px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  font-family: Courgette;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #f2f9fe;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%, #d6f0fd 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#f2f9fe), color-stop(100%,#d6f0fd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f9fe', endColorstr='#d6f0fd',GradientType=0 );
  margin: 120px auto 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: cyan;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 34.4444444444px;
}
.menu-item a:after, .menu-item a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-indeX: -1;
  background: white;
}

.menu-item a:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.menu-item a:before {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  top: -90px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">
  <nav class="menu">
    <input checked="checked" class="menu-toggler" id="menu-toggler" type="checkbox">
    <label for="menu-toggler">some text here</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

I'm still working on this and now I have reached up to X icon.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc354c, #0abfbc);
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-toggler:hover + label, .menu-toggler:hover + label:before, .menu-toggler:hover + label:after {
  background: white;
}

.menu-toggler:checked + label {
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-toggler:checked + label:before, .menu-toggler:checked + label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.menu-toggler:checked + label:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-toggler:checked + label:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translateX(-110px);
}
.menu-toggler:checked ~ ul .menu-item a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-toggler + label {
  width: 280px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 38px;
}
.menu-toggler + label:before, .menu-toggler + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.menu-toggler + label:before {
  top: 10px;
}
.menu-toggler + label:after {
  top: -10px;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) a {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) a {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) a {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) a {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) a {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) a {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 1025px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  font-family: Courgette;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #f2f9fe;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%, #d6f0fd 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#f2f9fe), color-stop(100%,#d6f0fd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 5%,#d6f0fd 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f9fe', endColorstr='#d6f0fd',GradientType=0 );
  margin: 120px auto 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: cyan;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 34.4444444444px;
}
.menu-item a:after, .menu-item a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-indeX: -1;
  background: white;
}

.menu-item a:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.menu-item a:before {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  top: -90px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">
  <nav class="menu">
    <input checked="checked" class="menu-toggler" id="menu-toggler" type="checkbox">
    <label for="menu-toggler">some text here</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
/* This is to make the cross hidden */
input#menu-toggler, label[for=menu-toggler]::before, label[for=menu-toggler]::after {
  display: none;
}

/* This is to remove background from the label provided that you give an 
id or something else to increase the specificity of the selector */
li#mi > a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
 <!-- I have add an id to the first li item in the list -->
      <li class="menu-item" id="mi">
        <a target="_blank">some text here</a>
      </li>
```

Comment: I haven't done it for the checked state but I think that you can do it on your own.

Comment: Comments are not meant to thank someone for the answer as per the guidelines of Stack overflow. You have the option of up vote to do that.